# Indoor plants on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Would a question about indoor plants, the selection & care thereof, be on or off-topic here?

Comment: Houseplants and their care, cultivation, and identification, are a significant feature of 'Gardening & Landscaping'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are on topic.

We have already answered some of them and they are definitely welcome here.

Comment: Definitely on topic. See: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/does-gardening-and-landscaping-only-include-outdoor-plants-or-indoor-plants-aswel/1073#1073